# ResourceNotFoundException in Symfony when route has a query string

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-routing

Odd issue

So in my administration bundle, I have routes like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/media")
 *
 * Class MediaController
 * @package AdminBundle\Controller
 */
class MediaController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("", name="media_home")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    { 
        // cool stuff happens here
    }
}
```

and this works great when accessing the page at `/media`

EXCEPT when I add a query string to the route. Like this: `/media?q=searchTest`. In fact when i do this to ANY route in my admin bundle, it always comes back with a `ResourceNotFoundException`

Here's the plain text stacktrace

```
[1] Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException: 
    at n/a
        in /var/www/myfunapp/app/cache/dev_admin/appDev_adminUrlMatcher.php line 378

    at appDev_adminUrlMatcher->match('/media?q=searchText')
        in /var/www/myfunapp/app/cache/dev_admin/classes.php line 3378

    at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->match('/media?q=searchText')
        in /var/www/myfunapp/src/AdminBundle/Listeners/AuthListener.php line 28

    at AdminBundle\Listeners\AuthListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
        in  line 

    at call_user_func(array(object(AuthListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
        in /var/www/myfunapp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php line 61

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
        in  line 

    at call_user_func(object(WrappedListener), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
        in /var/www/myfunapp/app/cache/dev_admin/classes.php line 4001

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
        in /var/www/myfunapp/app/cache/dev_admin/classes.php line 3934

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
        in /var/www/myfunapp/app/cache/dev_admin/classes.php line 4095

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
        in /var/www/myfunapp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 124

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
        in /var/www/myfunapp/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3098

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in /var/www/myfunapp/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3071

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /var/www/myfunapp/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3222

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /var/www/myfunapp/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2444

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /var/www/myfunapp/web/app_dev_admin.php line 30
```

POST works, but Query strings simply will not for whatever reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is not reaching to controller's method. you need to check var/www/myfunapp/src/AdminBundle/Listeners/AuthListener.php line 28. here some exception is coming. You have set Auth listner in kernel request so exception is coming from there.